# Is it expected that jQuery $('span').html() turns XHTML br tag to html syntax?

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a span tag like this:

```
 <span>Hi<br />SecondLine</span>
```

And I call this jQuery function:

```
 var html = $('span').html();
```

html is set to:

```
 Hi<br>SecondLine
```

Now, I realize the name of the function is html() and not xhtml().  But is this expected behavior?  Can I count on it, or do I alway need to check for a xhtml br tag and an html br tag, in say, this example:

```
function br2nl(text) {
    return text.replace(/<br \/>/gi, '\n').replace(/<br>/gi, '\n');
}
```

Comment: Your document is probably handled as HTML and not as XHTML.

Comment: Added case insensitve clause to regex since Firefox returns lowercase and IE returns uppercase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't. It just modifies the browser DOM.

It is up to the browser to serialise the DOM to HTML or XHTML as it desires when using innerHTML. Different browsers act differently.

Answer (score 3):

All browsers normalize HTML code while building their DOM tree. So, javascript gains access to already normalized DOM. With all tags properly closed and such.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually using XML, so it makes sense that the serialization doesn't use the XML syntax. See also [Ian Hickson's essay about sending XHTML as HTML](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml).