# TinyMCE turns <img /> into <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, codemirror

Tinymce is removing my img closing tag and producing invalid xhtml.

It turns this

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

Into this

```
<img src="image.jpg" data-mce-src="/../Index/image.jpg">
```

I'm also using codemagic, but when viewing the html it still shows . I have also tried including `<img></img>`, but the output is the same.

Thoughts?

Here are my options

```
var tinyMceOptions = {
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced',
    element_format : "xhtml",
    plugins: 'codemagic,wordcount,inlinepopups,sparkimage, sparklink',
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'formatselect,fontsizeselect,|, bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,sub,sup,|,sparklink,sparkimage,codemagic',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
    theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left',
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    //extended_valid_elements :"script[language<javascript|type|src]",
    skin: 'o2k7',
    width: '575px',
    height: '350px',
    forced_root_block : false,
    theme_advanced_blockformats: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p',
    relative_urls : false,
    setup : function (ed) {
        ed.onChange.add(function (ed, evt) {
            var val = $('iframe#_contentAreaID_ifr').contents().find('body').html();
                $('._hiddenContentContainer[data-contentid=' + currentTab + '] ._hiddenContentArea').val(val);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: Why use XHTML in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka The content needs to be valid xml since our CMS needs to parse through it and extract meta data on some elements.

Comment: Can you not alter your parser to allow both <img> and <img/>

Comment: @rlemon We're using c#'s XPathNavigator to parse the output of TinyMce, which is expecting valid xml. It would be a lot easier to figure out what setting is causing this in TinyMce. My other option is to check the TinyMce output before passing it to the XPathNavigator, but I really don't want to write something that has to parse (x)html myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue wasn't with TinyMCE, but instead with how we were getting the content out of the active editor. We used jquery's `$.html()` method instead of retriving the content using TinyMce's `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` method.

I initially came across [this](http://drupal.org/node/1363608) post talking about the same issue I'm having where the image tag was not output as xhtml. This led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102744/jquery-html-returns-invalid-img) stack post which explains why it doesn't work.

Quote from one of the answers

> .html() doesn't return the HTML or XHTML markup that was provided to
>   make the nodes, it returns the browser's internal representation of
>   the relevant nodes. This internal representation is not XHTML
>   compliant and is not made to be--it's technically an internal
>   implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

That is an issue within TinyMCE code itself.

It was never meant to be used with XHTML -- and if you do want to use it with that, then you have to edit the core.

[Here is an article that might highlight how to use strict XHTML with TinyMCE](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/how-to-produce-xhtml-10-strict-markup-with-tinymce)

Comment: The documentation on the [doctype](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:doctype) property, says that TinyMce will produce valid xhtml by default. That same page also points to [element_format](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:element_format) which by default is st to output xhtml, ie <br /> instead of <br>.

Your link ends up setting the doctype to strict xhtml, which the documentation states will not actually change how the output is generated, that's handled by the element_format property.