# jQuery create empty self-closed tag

Tags: jquery, xml, xhtml, tags, svg

I need to create an empty HTML tag which is self-closed, like

```
<line style="stroke:rgb(0,0,255); stroke-width:2"/>
```

with the following code:

```
$("<line/>").css({
    stroke: "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "stroke-width": 2
});
```

but I always get

```
<line style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255); stroke-width: 2px;"></line>
```

which doesn't work for SVG.

How I can explicitly cause jQuery to do that?

**UPDATED:**

I found a solution, but with pure JS:
[jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

Comment: Is it really a problem with the closing tag, or is it a problem with `stroke-width: 2px`? AFAIK `<line></line>` without any contents between the tags should be valid SVG.

Comment: Take a look at these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557295/jquery-html-and-self-closing-tags

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490909/is-it-expected-that-jquery-span-html-turns-xhtml-br-tag-to-html-syntax


Hope that helps

Comment: It would be helpful for others to point out the exact solution, not only the link to the large page where the solution have to be searched for :/ For me it helped to update `document.createElement('circle')` to `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle')`. After this update the browser created the self-closed `<circle />` and not `<circle></circle>` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SVG is XML not HTML so jQuery isn't going to follow the SVG document rules per se.

You could take a look at http://keith-wood.name/svg.html which seems to have a jQuery plugin for SVG.